# IntelliJ editors : select text using a pattern

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, intellij-plugin

I would like to be able to copy or cut text that's after a `:` in each line of a document. And then replace it with something else. The obvious way to do it would be to be able to put carets at each place where there is a `:` and go from there.

Is it possible to do that? Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are looking for this, select one occurrence of « : » and then :

- Select/unselect the next occurrence: Alt + J / Shift + Alt + J (Ctrl + G / Shift + Ctrl + G) for Mac OS X)
- Select all occurrences: Shift + Ctrl + Alt + J (Ctrl + Cmd + G for Mac OS X)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you